# Integrating MySQL with Python in Windows

Tags: python, mysql, windows

I am finding it difficult to use MySQL with Python in my windows system.

I am currently using Python 2.6. I have tried to compile MySQL-python-1.2.3b1 (which is supposed to work for Python 2.6 ?) source code using the provided setup scripts. The setup script runs and it doesn't report any error but it doesn't generate _mysql module.

I have also tried setting up MySQL for Python 2.5 with out success. The problem with using 2.5 is that Python 2.5 is compiled with visual studio 2003 (I installed it using the provided binaries). I have visual studio 2005 on my windows system. Hence setuptools fails to generate _mysql module.

Any help ?

Comment: Since 3 years have passed since this was asked, and 2 years since last high voted answer, see updated answer for Python 3.2 below (or see http://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL)

Answer (score 127):

[Download page for python-mysqldb](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python). The page includes binaries for 32 and 64 bit versions of for Python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7.

There's also [discussion on getting rid of the deprecation warning](http://sourceforge.net/forum/message.php?msg_id=5808948).

**UPDATE**: This is an old answer. Currently, I would recommend using PyMySQL. It's pure python, so it supports all OSes equally, it's almost a drop-in replacement for mysqldb, and it also works with python 3. The best way to install it is using pip. You can install it from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) (more instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/7581)), and then run:

```
pip install pymysql
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the first linked executable works with Python 2.6? The installation splash screen says it's only 2.5 - but I'm presuming the person who built it may just have not updated that line of documentation.

Comment: I installed python 2.7 x64 but while importing MySQLdb I'm getting 'ImportError: No module named _mysql_windows.api' error. pls anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Well after doing `pip install pymysql`, `syncdb` still complained about the missing `MySQLdb` module.

Comment: while i run this command in my windows 8.1 64 bit system it shows: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

Comment: @shailenTJ (and anyone with a similar problem) look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7166730/7581)

Comment: @hizbul25 pip installation is much simpler these days. Download get-pip.py from [here](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and run it. More info [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)

Comment: If anyone may be able to help, I'm having trouble using pymysql: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145845/cannot-make-remote-connection-with-pymysql-pymysql-err-internalerror-packet-se

Answer (score 31):

This may read like your grandpa givin advice, but all answers here did not mention the best way: go nd install [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) instead of python.org windows binaries. I was really wondering for a long time why Python development on windows was such a pita - until I installed activestate python. I am not affiliated with them. It is just the plain truth. Write it on every wall: **Python development on Windows = ActiveState**! 
you then just [`pypm install mysql-python`](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/) and everything works smoothly. **no compile orgy. no strange errors. no terror.** Just start coding and doing real work after five minutes. 
This is the only way to go on windows. Really.

Comment: It would be a perfect solution if a Business Edition subscription wasn't necessary...

Comment: @matheus.emm - Business Edition is not necessary for installing MySQLdb on Windows 32-bit.

Comment: @Sridhar What do you mean? When I tried to execute the command to install mysql-python a message was displayed saying that a Business Edition subscription was necessary. Is the a (legal) way to install mysql-python without this subscription on Windows 7 64 bits?

Comment: @matheus.emm - For free access, you can install ActivePython **32-bit** on your Windows 7 64-bit OS and then install mysql-python. ActivePython 64-bit does require a BE subscription for installing packages.

Comment: This is great advice. I think the Business Edition is well worth it if you are seriously using Python in production. If it saves you a few hours of work a month it pays for itself. All of these configuration headaches make me remember the open source business model: "Give them the software for free, but make it so hard to install and use they need to buy the manual and/or support." Only problem is many of these projects aren't providing or selling support because they see open source as an ideology instead of what it was intended to be, a business model. lolz

Comment: Just installed it using activepython community edition and it worked like a charm. Highly recommended

Comment: Great!Work for ActivePython on Win7!

Answer (score 15):

As Python newbie learning the Python ecosystem I've just completed this.

1. Install setuptools [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309412/how-to-setup-setuptools-for-python-2-6-on-windows)
2. Install MySQL 5.1. Download the 97.6MB MSI from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#win32) You can't use the essentials version because it doesnt contain the C libraries.
   Be sure to select a custom install, and mark the development tools / libraries for installation as that is not done by default. This is needed to get the C header files.
   You can verify you have done this correctly by looking in your install directory for a folder named "include". E.G C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\include. It should have a whole bunch of .h files.
3. Install Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Express 2008 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/) This is needed to get a C compiler.
4. Open up a command line as administrator (right click on the Cmd shortcut and then "run as administrator". Be sure to open a fresh window *after* you have installed those things or your path won't be updated and the install will still fail.
5. From the command prompt:

   easy_install -b C:\temp\sometempdir mysql-python

   That will fail - which is OK.

   Now open site.cfg in your temp directory C:\temp\sometempdir and edit the "registry_key" setting to:

   registry_key = SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.1

   now CD into your temp dir and:

   python setup.py clean

   python setup.py install

   You should be ready to rock!
6. [Here](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html) is a super simple script to start off learning the Python DB API for you - if you need it.

Answer (score 7):

I found a location were one person had successfully built mysql for python2.6, sharing the link, http://www.technicalbard.com/files/MySQL-python-1.2.2.win32-py2.6.exe

...you might see a warning while import MySQLdb which is fine and that won’t hurt anything,

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb__init__.py:34: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
from sets import ImmutableSet

Answer (score 5):

What about [pymysql](http://code.google.com/p/pymysql/)?  It's pure Python, and I've used it on Windows with considerable success, bypassing the difficulties of compiling and installing mysql-python.

Answer (score 2):

You're not the only person having problems with Python 2.6 and MySQL (http://blog.contriving.net/2009/03/04/using-python-26-mysql-on-windows-is-nearly-impossible/). Here's an explanation how it should run under Python 2.5 http://i.justrealized.com/2008/04/08/how-to-install-python-and-django-in-windows-vista/
Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use myPySQL. It's really easy to use; no compilation for windows, and even if you need to compile it for any reason, you only need Python and Visual C installed (not mysql).

http://code.google.com/p/mypysql/

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The precompiled binaries on http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python is just worked for me.

1. Open `MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` file with zip
   extractor program.
2. Copy the contents to
   `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\`

Answer (score 2):

On Python 3.4 I've installed mysqlclient from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ with pip install mysqlclient and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

There are [Windows binaries for MySQL-Python (2.4 & 2.5) available on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=22307&package_id=15775).  Have you tried those?

Comment: The 2.5 (and 2.4) binaries fail to install if only 2.6 is installed

Comment: That will be because the versions have to match.  There's a link to MySQL-Python 2.6 for Windows in this blog post but I haven't tried it: http://timvalenta.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/python-26-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Because I am running python in a (pylons/pyramid) virtualenv, I could not run the binary installers (helpfully) linked to previously.

I had problems following the steps with Willie's answer, but I determined that the problem is (probably) that I am running windows 7 x64 install, which puts the registry key for mysql in a slightly different location, specifically in my case (note: I am running version 5.5) in: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5".

HOWEVER, "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" cannot be included in the path or it will fail.

Also, I had to do a restart between steps 3 and 4.

After working through all of this, IMO it would have been smarter to run the entire python dev environment from cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Python 3.2 this seems the best solution I found so far

- for Python 2.4 - 3.2 [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL)
- for Python 2.3 - 2.6 [MySQL for Python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python)

Source: http://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also consider making use of [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org), it has mysql python libraries in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) with the [MySQL Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) to use MySQL on Windows.  [Unixodbc](http://www.unixodbc.org/) is also available to make the code compatible on Linux.  Pyodbc uses the standard Python [DB API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) so if you stick with that switching between MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQLite/ODBC/JDBC drivers etc. should be relatively painless.

Answer (score 0):

upvoted itsadok's answer because it led me to the installation for python 2.7 as well, which is located here: http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

Answer (score 0):

Got sick of the installation troubles with MySQLdb and tried [pymysql](http://www.pymysql.org/) instead.

Easy setup;

```
git clone https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL.git
python setup.py install
```

And APIs are pretty much the same.