# How to install mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql

I have downloaded mysqlDb, and while installing it I am getting errors like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\naresh\Desktop\MySQL-python-1.2.3c1>setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\naresh\Desktop\MySQL-python-1.2.3c1 
\setup.py",line15,      in  
metadata, options = get_config()
File "C:\Documents and Settings\naresh\Desktop\MySQL-python-1.2.3c1
\setup_windows.py",    line 7, in get_config
serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What can I do to address this?

Answer (score 6):

The registry key need to patch in that file, kindly refer to this thread

[Integrating MySQL with Python in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows)

or download prebuilt binary

http://www.codegood.com/archives/4

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire up `regedit` and make

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath`
and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\InstallGroup`

to look like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\InstallGroup`.

Comment: Did for me.  It's `regedit`, so YMMV.