# import error in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL for Python in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows)

I can't import the MySQLdb package in Python. How to install the msqldb package and where to place it in Python? Then when I compile the code there is an error like no module named MySQLdb. Python version is 2.6.4 then MySQLdb version is 1.2.3c1. Pls clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you use binary version installer (contains already compiled MySQLdb):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

http://www.codegood.com/archives/4