# pyodbc and mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, exception, pyodbc

I am unable to connect to mySQl db using pyodbc.

Here is a snippet of my script:

```
import pyodbc
import csv

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb; UID=root; PASSWORD=thatwouldbetelling;") 
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

with open('C:\\skunkworks\\archive\\data\\myfile.csv','r') as myfile:
    rows = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in rows:
        insert_str = 'INSERT into raw_data VALUES(something, something)'
        print insert_str
        #crsr.execute(insert_str)
    cnxn.commit()
    myfile.close()
```

I get this error at the pyodbc.connect() line:

> pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default
>   driver specified (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnectW)')

I have another question regarding this error (and Python scripts in general). When I run this as a script, it fails silently (I was expecting a stack trace). I have to type each line in manually to find where the error occured.

I am being a bit lazy for now (no exception handling) - is this normal behaviour of a Python script without exception handling to fail silently?

**[Edit]**

I am not using mysqldb because I am already using pyodbc to extract my data from another source (MS Access). Ok, not a good reason - but I am already grappling with pyodbc and I dont really fancy having to wrestle with another library/module/package(whatever its called in Python) for a "one off" job. I just want to move my data of from various data sources in the Windows environment to mySQl on Linux. once on Linux, I'll be back on terra firma.

That is the entire 'script' right there. I just saved the code above into a file with a .py extension, and I run python myscript.py at  the command line. I am running this on my XP machine

Comment: Why aren't you using the mysqldb driver?

Comment: "When I run this as a script"?  What did you actually do?  Please provide some hint as to what you did.  What OS?  What Shell?

Comment: "I dont really fancy having to wrestle with another library/module/package(whatever its called in Python) for a "one off" job"  That violates the Python world view.  It seems that all we ever do is download new packages and wrestle with them.  Using a package for it's intended purpose is important.  `pyodbc` probably cannot connect to MySQL.  Period.

Comment: The best way to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app is to check the list returned by calling `pyodbc.drivers()`.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same mistake so I went over all the version I was using for the connection. This is what I found out:

For Python 2.7 32 bits:
 - pyodbc must be 32bits
 - the DB Driver must be 32bits. (Microsoft Access should be 32 bits too)

For those who use the 64 bits version. You should check that everything is 64 bits too.

In my case I was trying to connecto to an Oracle DB and Microsoft Access DB so I had to make the following components match the architechture version:

- pyodbc (MS Access)
- python
- cx_Oracle (Oracle dialect for SQLalchemy)
- Oracle instantclient basic (Oracle. Do not forget to create the environment variable)
- py2exe (Making the excecutable app)

Comment: That was for me!! Many thanks, it could have been another 10 hours wasted... I just needed to install the 32bitversion of the driver and the 64bit dsn became 32/64 and it was connecting.

Comment: What command do you use to find if its 32 or 64 bit for pyobc, python, db driver, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Is that your driver name right?

You can **check your driver name in**
**Windows -> Control panel -> System and security -> Administrative tools -> ODBC Data Sources -> Driver tab**
**then copy the river name to the first parameter**

like

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=books; UID=root; PASSWORD=password;")
```

And my problem solved

or you may not install the driver and the step is simple.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to a remote server instead of localhost? I am using SERVER=10.0.1.235 as the remote mysql server IP, still it connects to the localhost 10.0.1.249. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

MySQLdb (or oursql) and pyodbc both have the same interface ([DB-API 2](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)), only you don't have to deal with ODBC's issues if you use the former. I strongly recommend you consider using MySQLdb (or oursql) instead.

Comment: MySQLdb dosen't install on Windows. Author pretty much accepts that its broken/unsupported on Windows.

Comment: I did mention another option.

Comment: Also, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

**First**, According to the [official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-without-dsn.html), if you want to connect without creating a DSN, you need to specify OPTION=3 in the connection string:

```
ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;USER=venu;PASSWORD=venu;OPTION=3;"
```

If that fails to work, I'd further troubleshoot by creating a DSN.

**Second**, no Python should not be failing silently.  If that is the case when you run your script, there is something else amiss.

Comment: For some strange reason, I'm getting the stack trace now at the console. Script still dosent work with the [modified] connection string you suggested. I found a solution though. I have installed MySQLdb on my Linux machine, so I will simply copy my csv file onto my Linux machine and do the data import on my Linux machine :(

Answer (score 2):

only need install mysql-connector-odbc-3.51.28-win32.msi.

and pyodbc-2.1.7.win32-py2.7.exe.

of course, you have ready installed MySQL and python 2.7.

example:

```
import pyodbc

cndBase = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; PORT=3306;DATABASE=nameDBase; UID=root; PASSWORD=12345;") 
ptdBase = cndBase.cursor()

query_str = 'SELECT* FROM nameTabla;'
rows  = ptdBase.execute(query_str)

for rw in rows:
    print list(rw)`enter code here`
```

Comment: 'dBase' is not defined.  Do you mean 'ptdBase'?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. It seemed the driver i was using to make the connection was not the driver installed in my system. 
Type ODBC on windows run and select ODBC Data Source(32/64) based on where you have installed the driver. 
From there click on System DSN and click add. From there you can see the MySQL driver installed in your system. Use the ANSI driver in your code where you are making the connection.