# which version of MySQL driver to use in Pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to MYSQl db Server using pyodbc module.

```
with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.6 Driver};SERVER=XX.XX.X.XX;PORT=3306;DATABASE=ssc;UID=Pra;PASSWORD=welcome;') as cnxn:

    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('insert into ....')
```

When I ran the above code in python I am encountering an error '*local variable 'cnxn' referenced before assignment*'I am working on MySQL workbench 6.2 and I am not sure which version of MySQL driver to use.

Answer (score 1):

This specific error isn't a problem with the driver, the `cnxn` object is never created.

Change your code to:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.6 Driver};SERVER=XX.XX.X.XX;PORT=3306;DATABASE=ssc;UID=Pra;PASSWORD=welcome;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('insert into ....')
```

The pyodbc wiki has a [getting started](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted) section that is helpful.

For further reading, see pyodbc [issue 100](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=100) concerning use of `with`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I printed the stack trace this is an the error that I got '('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) '.The exact connect statement that I am using is this 
cnxn= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL Driver};SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;DATABASE=ssc;UID=Pra;PWD=welcome;OPTION=3')

Comment: @Pranay Now you're seeing the driver problem. Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982174/pyodbc-and-mysql?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the MySQL driver for Python?

```
pip install MySQL-python
```