# How to connect to Azure MySQL from Azure Functions by Python

Tags: python, mysql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I am trying to;

1. Run the python code triggered by Cosmos DB when cosmos DB receives the data..
2. The python code in Azure Functions has code to ingest data from Azure MySQL.

What I have done are;

- . Wrote python in Azure Functions and run it with triggered by Cosmos
  DB. This was successful.
- . Installed mysql.connector referred to
  https://prmadi.com/running-python-code-on-azure-functions-app/ and
  run the code to connect to Azure MySQL, but It does not work.

Do you know how to install mysql module for Python to Azure Functions and connect to the database?

Thanks!

Comment: Any progress now?

Comment: Jay, Thanks. I will work on this in a couple of hours later. will post a feedback.

Comment: Run this "python -m pip install MySQLdb" and received the below.                            InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQLdb

Comment: Please change the module to pyodbc and try again. Please refer to this thread about connecting mysql db via pyodbc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982174/pyodbc-and-mysql

Comment: Thanks. pyodbc has been successfully installed, but Functions log like "2017-11-21T10:16:53.927 Exception while executing function: Functions.alertemail. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: ."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description ,I think your issue is about how to install the Python third-party module in the Azure function app.

Please refer to the steps as below :

Step 1 :

login kudu : `https://Your_APP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

Run Below command in `d:/home/site/wwwroot/<your function name>` folder.(will take some time)

```
python -m virtualenv myvenv
```

Step 2 :

Load the env via the below command in `env/Scripts` folder.

```
activate.bat
```

Step 3 :

Your shell should be now prefixed by (env).

Update pip

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Install what you need

```
python -m pip install MySQLdb
```

Step 4 :

In your code, update the sys.path to add this venv:

```
import sys, os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'env/Lib/site-packages')))
```

Then connect to mysql db via the snippet of code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

# Connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="appuser",
                     passwd="",
                     db="onco")

cursor = db.cursor()

# Execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM location")

# Commit your changes if writing
# In this case, we are only reading data
# db.commit()

# Get the number of rows in the resultset
numrows = cursor.rowcount

# Get and display one row at a time
for x in range(0, numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row[0], "-->", row[1]

# Close the connection
db.close()
```

Hope it helps you.