# Error compiling coverage.py on MacOSX

Tags: python, macos, installation, compiler-errors, coverage.py

I tried to install [coverage 3.4](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) on my MacBook running on current Mac OS X 10.6.7. This is what I got as an error:

```
$ easy_install coverage
install_dir /Users/jammon/workspace/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
Searching for coverage
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/coverage/
Reading http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/coverage.html
Reading http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage
Reading http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/3.4b1
Reading http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/3.4b2
Best match: coverage 3.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/coverage/coverage-3.4.tar.gz#md5=46782809578c8fd29912c124d2420842
Processing coverage-3.4.tar.gz
Running coverage-3.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/10/10P5vwX-Ghmkg8s25PMr3E+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-UcskZB/coverage-3.4/egg-dist-tmp-QCs3YS
no previously-included directories found matching 'test'
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
                 from coverage/tracer.c:3:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
                 from coverage/tracer.c:3:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/10/10P5vwX-Ghmkg8s25PMr3E+++TI/-Tmp-//ccAYGjpc.out
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Can anybody make sense from that? I simply don't understand what is wrong. Or how I can fix it.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Update:
After Ned's comment I tried it with `easy_install -vv coverage`; the result is not much different:

```
...
creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/coverage
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c coverage/tracer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/coverage/tracer.o
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
                 from coverage/tracer.c:3:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
                 from coverage/tracer.c:3:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/10/10P5vwX-Ghmkg8s25PMr3E+++TI/-Tmp-//ccZQsHOd.out
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

As far as I remember, I compiled python from the sources the standard way, it was not a binary distribution. I tried it with and without `virtualenv`.

Comment: That's rather odd. There shouldn't be a problem installing this.  Try running again with `easy_install -vv coverage` and report back the entire `gcc` command.  There *might* be something wrong with your 10.4u SDK.  You could try reinstalling that from an Xcode 3 installer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most recent version of XCode removes support for compiling to the old PowerPC (PPC) architecture. Unfortunately, Python on Mac typically still tries to build C extensions for PPC as well as x86. To get around this, prefix commands like 'setup.py install' or 'easy_install' with an ARCHFLAGS setting that only includes the architectures you want to build for:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" easy_install coverage
```

Comment: That really sounds like the solution; but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I really have to get some time to do some research for the cause of the problem.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you still get `gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c coverage/tracer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/coverage/tracer.o
` with the `-arch ppc` in the middle? That's the bad part.

Comment: This worked for me, compiling the latest version of lxml (2.3.5) on Mac OS X 10.8 (mountain lion).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can [use **ActivePython**](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/coverage/) to obviate the need to [compile things yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows/3242143#3242143):

```
$ pypm install coverage
The following packages will be installed into "~/Library/Python/2.7" (2.7):
 coverage-3.4
Get: [pypm-free.activestate.com] coverage 3.4
Installing coverage-3.4                                  
Fixing script ~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/coverage
$
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling  I found a solution in [this blogpost and the comments](http://cd34.com/blog/programming/python/mysql-python-and-snow-leopard/), that worked for me: I removed /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk, then installing coverage (and reportlab, which showed the same problem) worked just as expected.

As far as I understood, the handling of stdarg.h has changed in some version of gcc, resulting in the described problem.