# how do I install httplib2 for python under windows 7 64?

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, installation, httplib2

Only instructions I can find refer to unix/linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to go through [compile orgy, stranger errors and terror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows/3242143#3242143),

1. [Install ActivePython](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/httplib2/) (32-bit)
2. Open Command Prompt and type `pypm install httplib2`

Answer (score 4):

```
cd httplib2-0.6.0
python setup.py install
```

Comment: thanks, ran it using 'setup.py install' - if i put 'python' in front it just threw the error 'is not recognized as an internal or external command'

try to use the lib in python:

`o = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() )
NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined`

Comment: not working :-( the following code:
`# build opener with HTTPCookieProcessor
o = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() )
urllib2.install_opener( o )`
just throws this error:
`    o = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() )
NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined`

Comment: @4rd2: You need to import urllib2 before you can use it. If you're new to Python, you might want to look over a tutorial. There are plenty online - here's one: http://diveintopython.org/toc/index.html