# Zope 3 + windows + MySQL - How to install ZMySQLDA on windows?

Tags: python, mysql, windows, zope, python-db-api

I'm looking for instructions 'how to install  ZMySQLDA on windows'

I have installed python 2.4, Zope 3, and I have downloaded The Zope MySQL Database Adapter (ZMySQLDA), available from http://www.zope.org/Members/adustman/Products/ZMySQLDA

I unpacked and copied library to zope/lip/python/Products directory and I restarted Zope server but... my ZMySQLDA isn't avaliable from my admin panel, what am I doing wrong?

How to connect Zope and MySQL on win correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zope 3 and current Products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125410/zope-3-and-current-products)

Comment: no idea why the same issues must be posted twice within one day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZMySQLDA is a Zope2 Product; in Zope 3 I'd use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) integrated with [zope.sqlalchemy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.sqlalchemy) (and optionally [z3c.saconfig](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.saconfig)) to access MySQL data in your application.

Note that your biggest problem is most likely one of being able to find the python MySQL drivers. See [Integrating MySQL with Python in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows) for help on that part (scan through the answers for the python-2.4 links).

Comment: Thanks for answers, There are my first steps in Zope world and it is not clear for me which products are for Zope 2 and wich for Zope 3. 
I must connect to 3 batabases in my project:
 - mysql 
 - postgres
 - MS Server

Which Zope products will be the best?
Is only sqlalchemy ok? Is there any other solution?

Comment: SQLAlchemy connects to all of them, so zope.sqlalchemy at least, and if you need a Database Adapter (basically if you need a zope object representing a SQL query), then SQLAlchemyDA.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'd use SQLAlchemyDA, which relies on zope.sqlalchemy.  There's still plenty of reason to use Database adapters in a Zope 3 world.

Starting your instance in "debug" mode will usually show if you are missing python drivers.