# Zope 3 and current Products

Tags: python, zope3

On this page http://www.zope.org/Products at the bottom is a full list of Zope products but most of them are available for Zope 2 not for Zope 3 e.g. ZMySQLDA.

Where I can find list of all Products only for Zope 3? Or maybe I am wrong and this list is for Zope2 and Zope3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like a "product" for Zope 3. In particular there is nothing like "Zope 3" anymore - there is only the Zope Tool Kit aka ZTK and the "Bluebream" application server (based on ZTK). The term "Zope 3" is dead.

In general you can integrate external database on top of SQLAlchemy e.g. through the zope.sqlalchemy package (transactional support with the ZODB).

Apart from that: you can use most Python packages directly with Zope 2, ZTK or Bluebream (where is makes sense). Always check on PyPI if there is something related to the Zope specific integration (search by classifier or fulltext search). You may also check svn.zope.org - at least all relevant packages are in the repository - so may check out for related packages by their names.

Comment: I believe Zope Page Templates (ZPT) are still in fairly heavy use also.

Comment: It's one of several surviving technologies that originated with Zope; you seemed to be enumerating some of these in your response, so I was adding this as another.  Maybe I misunderstood your response?

Answer (score 1):

Zope3 (or Zope Toolkit, ZTK) is a collection of Python libraries, used by various projects, with BlueBream being one of them, classic Zope2 another. As such, there is no need to provide specialized "Products" for these anymore.

You use the libraries like you would use other Python libraries; e.g. you write integration code that uses these libraries to build your application.

There may be server-specific packages, such as for Plone, BlueBream or Grok, that depend on features provided by those servers. The fact that those servers rely heavily on the Zope Toolkit is a happistance that has nothing to do with providing add-ons for those servers.