# How can access MySQL with Python?

Tags: python, mysql

How can I access MySQL with Python on windows environment ?

I took a look to [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) but in the README says:

"I don't do Windows. However if someone provides me with a package for Windows, I'll make it available."

So is there easy way to access MySQL on Windows or I should install Red Hat & go from there?

Comment: You might want to look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The README doesn't mean MySQLdb isn't available for Windows. It only means that the library's maintainer doesn't provide binaries for Windows.

You can still get these binaries for Windows either by 1) compiling them yourself or 2) getting them compiled from some third party.

I suggest you to do the latter:

- Check out page ["MySQL-python Windows 64bit and 32bit distributions"](http://www.codegood.com/archives/4)
- Locate .exe that matches your OS and Python versions and install it
- You are done

Comment: Thanks for your fast response !