# importing MySQL in django

Tags: mysql, django

I downloaded The SQL API from here 
http://www.djangoproject.com/r/python-mysql/ (the official site) the problem is I don't know how to import it in django.
for example whrn I type this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import MySQLdb
....
...
..
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

where should I extract the files, and what do I have to change to make it work ?

Answer (score 3):

When you extract it , cd into where you extracted it and run the setup.py file 
 `python setup.py install`

Comment: And just in case OP is using Windows, I'll link the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to use mysql as database for django project you need:**

1. install **mysql.connector** (`pip install mysql-connector`)
2. in settings.py setup default database for django project

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
           'NAME': 'name of your schema in mysql',
           'USER': 'root',
           'PASSWORD': '12345678',
           'HOST': 'localhost',
           'PORT': '3306',
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use commands like result = Something.objects.all() to query database (read django shell documentation for more info how to insert and take data from database [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/))

**If you just want to use mysql commands and data in django module, you use same system like in simple python:**

1. install mysql.connector (`pip install mysql-connector`)
2. include it in module (`import mysql.connector`)
3. create connection (`conection= mysql.connector.connect(user='', host='', port='', password=''`)
4. create instance for communication with database (`myquery=conection.cursor()`)
5. make your datatbase query (`myquery.execute("select yourdata from data.table")`)
6. take results from myquery (`for q in myquery: results += q`)

Example:

```
import mysql.connector


conection= mysql.connector.connect(user='root', 
host='localhost', port='3306', password='12345678')
myquery=conection.cursor()
myquery.execute("select something from data.table")

for q in myquery:
    results += q
```