# installing mysql for python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, installation, python-2.7

```
D:\PythonPack\MySQL-python-1.2.3>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "D:\PythonPack\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_confi
g
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_ke
y'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am trying to install mysqldb for python in windows7 and run into that error message

Do you have an idea how I can make it work ? I already have pythonsetuptool installed

Comment: This is not an answer, but just a hint - I'm using sqlite DB on windows computer (development) and MySQL on servr (production).

Comment: This is my first program with sqlite3 , does it have a tool like phpmyadmin for me to create and handle tables ? Or any way like a commandline tool for me to do so in console windows prompt

Comment: You should use `manage.py syncdb` to create tables.

Comment: @AleksejVasinov if the OP is using Django, which is not at all obvious since it hasn't been mentioned at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are many ways and i tried them for few hours and realize its time waste process bcoz MYSQLdb is vary from version to version i.e 2.6,2.7 and 3.2 but all those are confuse and time waste processes,
Instead best way is to get precompiled executables from : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs .
here choose version wise links like python 2.7 and 32bit so that you won't get any errors and now run the downloaded file, finally set **path** in environment variables.
Now open python IDLE editor or from command prompt c:>python
import MySQLdb

if u don't get any errors then it's working fine...enjoy with u r work

Answer (score 0):

Just install with the exe from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

And maybe you can find more information about this in the previous asked questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows).