# create date variable regardless the format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have strings like this:

```
3/11/2014
3 January 2014
3rd 11 2014
3th January 2014
```

Is there any posiblity that I can make a date variable from those strings?

#### I know that

i can make a date variable from string **with format** like this:

```
datetime.strptime("3-11-2014","%d-%m-%Y").date()
```

#### my problem

the format of the date is **unknown**

so onetime it is `3/11/2014`, another time it is `3-11-2014`, another time it is `3th janary 2014`

Comment: Are there restrictions on what the possible date formats are? 3-11-2014 could be November 3rd or it could be March 11th.

Comment: @pandubear yes that is a posibllity too

Answer (score 3):

Use dateutil's [`parse`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) function:

```
In [217]:

dates=['3/11/2014',
'3 January 2014',
'3rd 11 2014',
'3th January 2014']

import dateutil as dt
In [218]:

for date in dates:
    print(dt.parser.parse(date))
2014-03-11 00:00:00
2014-01-03 00:00:00
2014-03-11 00:00:00
2014-01-03 00:00:00
```

For the situation where you know the year or day is first you can set param `yearfirst=True` and `dayfirst=True`, this assumes that this convention is maintained throughout, if not then it is impossible to disambiguate the dates.

Comment: i have just one input, not list of inputs, also, what is `in[217` ?

Comment: there is not model called "dateutil"

Comment: My code is just an example, the `in[217]` is IPython output, ignore it, it is not python code as such. The point being that dateutils's `parse` method should handle most cases

Comment: You need to install it, if you have pip installed then this is simply `pip install python-dateutil` from your command line also there are other methods see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962714/installing-python-dateutil

Comment: now I am able to import `dateutil` but i got this error `parser` is not existed

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli are you importing the same as my code or as `import dateutil` rather than `import dateutil as dt`? If the former then you would need to do `dateutil.parser.parse`