# What are the dependencies for using pylab?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I needed to use plotting features in python 2.7 hence I downloaded and installed matplotlib package (v1.3.1). When I types import pylab in IDLE I got an exception saying dateutils was needed by matplotlib. So I installed that. Then I was told pyparsing was needed so I installed that. Now I am getting the message that numpy is needed

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pylab

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pylab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Is there a way to know what are all the dependencies that are needed to use pylab so I don't have to download one by one or am I doing something wrong in the installation that is causing so many missing packages?

Comment: How did you manage to install matplotlib without all the dependencies?  For the record, the list is here: http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#build-requirements

Answer (score 0):

OK. I just installed numpy and it seemed to now import pylab correctly. So looks like this was the last package needed. Just is case anyone has an issue like this I am listing which packages I had to download to get to this:

1. matplotlib
2. dateutils
3. pyparsing
4. numpy

Installing #1, 3, and 4 was fairly straightforward as these had installers which found the installed python version and accordingly installed in correct location. However, for #2 I had to you download the tar.gz file. The unzip and untar it and manually copy the dateutil folder from the unpackaged folder into the python installation (also see [How to install python-dateutil on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879156/how-to-install-python-dateutil-on-windows?rq=1))