# installing easy_install for Python 2.6.2 (missing?)

Tags: python, easy-install

I am not a python user, I'm just trying to get couchdb-dump up and running and it's in an "egg" file which I guess needs easy_install. I have Python 2.6.2 running on my computer but it seems to know nothing about easy_install or setuptools... help! What can I do to fix this???

**edit:** you may note from the [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows) page that there are Windows .exe installers for 2.3, 2.4, and 2.5, but not 2.6. What the heck?!?!

argh, this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309412/how-to-setup-setuptools-for-python-2-6-on-windows), sorry.

p.s. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309412/how-to-setup-setuptools-for-python-2-6-on-windows/425318#425318) is the one that seemed simplest and it worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup setuptools for python 2.6 on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309412/how-to-setup-setuptools-for-python-2-6-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
... has been updated and has windows installers for Python 2.6 and 2.7

(note: if you need 64-bit windows installer: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 7):

I don't like the whole easy_install thing either.

But the solution is to download the source, untar it, and type

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

For installing setuptools for 2.6 download "ez_setup.py" from:

http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/branches/setuptools-0.6/#egg=setuptools-dev06

And run it.  setuptools should be installed.
This will place easy_install in your python26/Scripts directory, make sure this is in your PATH, and then you should be able to use easy_install.