# easy_install python

Tags: python, windows-7, easy-install

What to do after doing all the steps to install easy_install python & the paths are available in the script what shall I do I'm really fed up because I have done all steps several time then open idle & write easy_install tell me invalid!

Comment: First, how about tell us what do you want to do ?

Comment: Second, tell us exactly what you did and exactly what error you got.

Comment: hi tg 
i want to install easy_install to  be able to import packetss like geopy

Comment: hi s.lott
see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309412/how-to-setup-setuptools-for-python-2-6-on-windows   w did option 2

Comment: @user696825: Please **update** your question to contain what you actually did.  Also please don't use tweetspeak.  This isn't twitter.  Please use words.  Most important: **update** the question with all the details.  Don't add comments, please.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to install easy_install to be able to import packages like geopy

Don't trouble yourself with installing setuptools. ActivePython already includes easy_install, pip, [PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/geopy/) and virtualenv.

1. Install [**ActivePython**](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645943/mysql-for-python-in-windows/3242143#3242143))
2. Open Command Prompt and type `pypm install geopy`