# No module named 'setuptools', even though the module is installed

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the openpyxl package with pip, using Windows.

```
PS C:\Scripts> pip install openpyxl
Collecting openpyxl
    Using cached openpyxl-2.5.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

When I run the setuptools installation I get:

```
PS C:\Scripts> pip install setuptools
>>
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\scripts\lib\site-packages
```

I tried uninstalling and installing the setuptools again, but no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
PS C:\Users\dolinar\Desktop\setuptools-38.4.0> python .\easy_install.py
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-9076.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

C:Lib\site-packages\

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).
```

The directory exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be installed system-wide. If you are using Ubuntu/Debian:

```
apt-get install -y python-setuptools
```

If you are on Windows, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309783/4137194) to install setup tools.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on Windows

Comment: Nope.
Got error message (you can see it in original post)

Comment: Alright purged python and reinstalled it, works now. Thank you for your help.